# NestJS JwtStrategy use configService to pass secret key

Tags: typescript, nestjs, passport-jwt

I have the JwtStrategy class from docs example (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication):

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
        private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    ) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: this.configService.getSecretKey,
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

When I am trying access `this` before calling super() I get an error. But I still want to use configService to get secret key.

I know that I can use env var to do that, but service approach is more clearer solution, in my opinion.

How can I use configService or maybe get value from it and pass to super() call? Thanks.

Comment: Using nestjs version 9 it is not working

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just remove `this.`, see here:

```
secretOrKey: configService.getSecretKey
```

It will work since `configService` has been passed as a parameter.

Comment: To avoid "Property 'configService' is declared but its value is never read." I also had to drop the `private` from `private readonly configService: ConfigService`.

Comment: I can confirm, you cannot have `private` keyword and use that property in the `super()` call within `constructor`

Comment: To add on the above answer and comment, replace `private` with `protected`

Comment: But nothing said here helped to me. I have the same code.

Answer (score 1):

in nestjs v10.0.0 this can be achived like this

**jwt.strategy.ts**

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(PassportJwtStrategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    @Inject(ConfigService) private readonly configService: ConfigService, // <- injected config service here
  ) {
    console.log(`${configService.get('JWT_SECRET')}`);
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: configService.getOrThrow('JWT_SECRET'), // <- using config service inside the super constructor
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validationSchema: envValidationSchema,
      isGlobal: true, // <- * register the config module globally
      validationOptions: {
        allowUnknown: true,
        abortEarly: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```