# How can I user configService in super()?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I have a question about setting environmental variables.

In official document, it says using ConfigModule in this case, but my case is a exception case.

Because I would like to use it in super() in constructor.

My code is the below.

Is there any solution in this case?

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thank you all your support!!

```js
// jwt.strategy.ts

import { UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { JwtPayload } from './jwt-payload.interface';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
        private userRepository: UserRepository,
        private configService: ConfigService,
    ) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: configService.get('JWT_TOKEN'),
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
        const { username } = payload;
        const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ username });

        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: check this answer may it works for you : [configService o pass secret key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977202/nestjs-jwtstrategy-use-configservice-to-pass-secret-key)

Answer (score 9):

I would also like to point out that since you are not using the `configService` anywhere but in the `super()` call the usage of `private` keyword in front of it is redundant

You can try using `this.configService.get('JWT_TOKEN')` but it will simply yell at you that you haven't called super

Removing the private keyword will simply avoid making the `configService` as a class variable and simply treat it as some option passed into it

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Because you can't access `this` inside `super` call, remove the `private` keyword and get config by `configService.get('JWT_TOKEN')`.

Comment: Agree with the previous comment, this should be the accepted answer. Thanks @aekant, it helped

Answer (score 2):

For your `Strategy` you're missing the `@Injectable()` which tells Nest that it needs to inject the dependencies defined in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the configModule into your module class for the configService to work. Also, add @Injectable() right above the class name to indicate it is a provider.

This is how you import the module.

```
//auth.module.ts    
    
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  provider:[JwtStrategy]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

NestJs resolves the dependencies between them.

see: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice