# Nest.js this not working in constructor super

Tags: node.js, this

I try add `configService` to JwtStrategy:

```
  constructor(readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      //...
      secretOrKey: this.configService.get('SECRET_KEY'),
    });
  }
```

I'm using this [instruction](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice). But TS return me error:

> 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a
> derived class.

When I remove `this` (like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983040/6678345)), then Nest return another error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtStrategy (?). Please make
> sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the
> AuthModule context.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by adding `ConfigService` to `providers` in `auth.module.ts` file:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, ConfigService],
  exports: [JwtStrategy],
})
```

I had to remove `private` from `constructor` and remove `this` from `configService`.